# why my python code doesn't represent some of characters?

Tags: python

```
for i in  xrange(256):
    print str(i)+' : '+chr(i)
```

when this code run [some of characters not shown and instead them show squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG00T.png)

I've been trying but I could not fix the problem 
even when I run this code :

```
print "\a"
```

nothing happens
I don't hear bell sound
[edit] : on cmd or terminal work correctly

Comment: You need to take a look at the ASCII Table: http://www.asciitable.com

Comment: try checking if `chr(i).isprintable()` since not all of the characters are printable/

Answer (score 1):

well you are printing out ascii characters. the numbers you print out are not alphabetical characters in the first place, cf [here](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Answer (score 0):

You can't print all ascii characters.Here you can find all the ascii characters.

```
print ' '.join([chr(i) for i in range(128)])
```

Here is the result of this

```
'\x00 \x01 \x02 \x03 \x04 \x05 \x06 \x07 \x08 \t \n \x0b \x0c \r \x0e \x0f \x10 \x11 \x12 \x13 \x14 \x15 \x16 \x17 \x18 \x19 \x1a \x1b \x1c \x1d \x1e \x1f   ! " # $ % & \' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \\ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~ \x7f'
```

And in this printable characters are follows. Which ca find like this.

```
In [34]: import string
In [35]: print string.printable
```

**Result**

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

Comment: print "bos\rb" not display bob

Answer (score 0):

this problem causes by python idle and when code run in terminal or cmd bell sound will hear